# ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1..2)):

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

Working with a ruby on rails app, rails 7 and ActiveStorage installed. I have a model Order, in my order.rb I include

```
    has_many_attached :files
```

My orders_controller.rb includes this

```
    def order_params                                                                                                                        
       params.require(:order).permit(
       ...
       :files [],
      ...
    end
```

And in my Order form I have something like:

```
    <%= f.label :files, t(".anade_los_documentos") %>
    <%= f.file_field :files, class: 'form-control', placeholder: 0, multiple: true, onchange: "this.form.requestSubmit()" %>
```

I get this error

```
    ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1..2)):

    app/controllers/orders_controller.rb:808:in `[]'
```

The line 808 is where I include my :files [] within order_params. But if I'm right, I'm passing files in the update call (see below)

```
    Processing by OrdersController#update as TURBO_STREAM
      Parameters: 
      {"authenticity_token"=>"[FILTERED]", "order"=>{"email"=>"[FILTERED]", "typedocument"=>"Acta de defunción", {
      "authenticity_token" => "[FILTERED]", "order" => {
        "email" => "[FILTERED]", "typedocument" => "Acta de defunción", "customtz" => "Europe/Brussels", 
        "files" => ["", 
          # < ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile: 0x0000000109c1a520 @tempfile = # < Tempfile: /var/folders / p2 / tt3rjy5s0m917fhkc4nkfnf80000gp / T / RackMultipart20230830 - 97394 - ginuqt.pdf > , @original_filename = "doc 1.pdf", @content_type = "application/pdf", @headers = "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"order[files][]\"; filename=\"doc 1.pdf\"\r\nContent-Type: application/pdf\r\n" > , 
          # < ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile: 0x0000000109c1a4d0 @tempfile = # < Tempfile: /var/folders / p2 / tt3rjy5s0m917fhkc4nkfnf80000gp / T / RackMultipart20230830 - 97394 - xguoyp.pdf > , @original_filename = "doc 2.pdf", @content_type = "application/pdf", @headers = "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"order[files][]\"; filename=\"doc 2.pdf\"\r\nContent-Type: application/pdf\r\n" > ], 
        "pages" => "1", 
        "ordertype" => "standardCertifiedTranslation", 
        "servicenotarisation" => "0", 
        "serviceapostille" => "0", 
        "country" => "Selecciona uno", 
        "urgtypev2" => "no", 
        "physicalcopyv2" => "false", 
        "street" => "", 
        "poblacion" => "", 
        "zipcode" => "", 
        "state" => "", 
        "shippingv2" => "standard", 
        "prenotes" => ""
      }, 
      "locale" => "es", "id" => "716"
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is in `:files []` because it needs to be `files: []`

Answer (score 2):

This line raised error

```rb
:files [],
```

When you write this code, Ruby interpreter thinks this is `:files.[]()` — [`Symbol#[]`](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/master/Symbol.html#method-i-5B-5D) method (not an empty array) and you call it without arguments

It is equivalent of `:files.to_s.slice`, that uses 1..2 arguments

[`ActionController::Parameters#permit`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html#method-i-permit) documentation says that if you want to declare that the parameter should be an array, you need to pass empty array as value of the hash

```rb
files: [],
```